# AngularJS Binding inputs to different table columns

Tags: angularjs, json

I am relatively new to Angular, but have been enjoying it. I am working on a personal project taking a list of football players and displaying the list on a page. I want the user to be able to refine the search by name, position AND team. So they could potentially search for all Johns playing QB on the Colts.

I am using a JSON file procured from an online API that I just downloaded and am using locally.

The list is displayed fine and the search by name and position work well, but the search by team is a little funky. It may have something to do with the structure of the JSON file. All relevant code is below. Sorry for the length on a couple of them, but I wanted to be as thorough as possible.

My players.html:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" ng-controller="PlayerController">
<h2>Player Stats</h2>

{{ sortType }}
<section class="search">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Search by Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="query" ng-model="query" min="1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Search by Position</label>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="position">
                <option value="all" selected>All positions</option>
                <optgroup label="Offense">
                    <option>QB</option>
                    <option>HB</option>
                    <option>FB</option>
                    <option>WR</option>
                    <option>TE</option>
                    <option>LT</option>
                    <option>LG</option>
                    <option>C</option>
                    <option>RG</option>
                    <option>RT</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Defense">
                    <option>RE</option>
                    <option>LE</option>
                    <option>DT</option>
                    <option>OLB</option>
                    <option>MLB</option>
                    <option>ILB</option>
                    <option>LB</option>
                    <option>CB</option>
                    <option>SS</option>
                    <option>FS</option>
                    <option>K</option>
                    <option>P</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Search by Team</label>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="team">
                <option value="all" selected>All Teams</option>
                <optgroup label="AFC East">
                    <option value="NE">New England Patriots</option>
                    <option value="BUF">Buffalo Bills</option>
                    <option value="NYJ">New York Jets</option>
                    <option value="MIA">Miami Dolphins</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="AFC North">
                    <option value="PIT">Pittsburgh Steelers</option>
                    <option value="BAL">Baltimore Ravens</option>
                    <option value="CIN">Cinncinati Bengals</option>
                    <option value="CLE">Cleveland Browns</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="AFC South">
                    <option value="HOU">Houston Texans</option>
                    <option value="TEN">Tennessee Titans</option>
                    <option value="IND">Indianapolis Colts</option>
                    <option value="JAC">Jacksonville Jaguars</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="AFC West">
                    <option value="OAK">Oakland Raiders</option>
                    <option value="DEN">Denver Broncos</option>
                    <option value="KC">Kansas City Chiefs</option>
                    <option value="SD">San Diego Chargers</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="NFC East">
                    <option value="DAL">Dallas Cowboys</option>
                    <option value="PHI">Philidelphia Eagles</option>
                    <option value="WAS">Washington Redskins</option>
                    <option value="NYG">New York Giants</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="NFC North">
                    <option value="MIN">Minnesotta Vikings</option>
                    <option value="GB">Green Bay Packers</option>
                    <option value="DET">Detroit Lions</option>
                    <option value="CHI">Chicago Bears</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="NFC South">
                    <option value="ATL">Atlanta Falcons</option>
                    <option value="TB">Tampa Bay Buccaneers</option>
                    <option value="NO">New Orleans Saints</option>
                    <option value="CAR">Carolina Panthers</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="NFC West">
                    <option value="SEA">Seattle Seahawks</option>
                    <option value="STL">St Louis Rams</option>
                    <option value="ARI">Arizona Cardinals</option>
                    <option value="SF">San Fransisco 49ers</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-click="sort('LastName') ">Name <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortType=='LastName'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></th>
            <th ng-click="sort('Position') ">Position <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortType=='Position'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></th>
            <th ng-click="sort('JerseyNumber') ">Number <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortType=='JerseyNumber'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></th>
            <th ng-click="sort('Abbreviation') ">Team <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortType=='Abbreviation'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="player in playerList | filter: query || position || team | orderObjectBy: sortType">
            <td><a href="#/player-detail/{{ player.player.ID }}">{{ player.player.FirstName }} {{ player.player.LastName }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ player.player.Position }}</td>
            <td>#{{ player.player.JerseyNumber }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.team.Abbreviation }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!--dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls-->
```

My PlayerController:

```
nflControllers.controller('PlayerController', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.msg = 'player controller';
$scope.sortType = 'LastName';

$scope.sort = function(key) {
    $scope.sortType = key;
}

$http.get('js/json/players.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.playerList = response.data.cumulativeplayerstats.playerstatsentry;
    //console.log($scope.playerList)
});
```

});

And sample of the player.json:

```
{"cumulativeplayerstats":{  
  "lastUpdatedOn":"2016-07-11 10:29:58 PM",
  "playerstatsentry":[  
     {  
        "player":{  
           "ID":"6923",
           "LastName":"Abbrederis",
           "FirstName":"Jared",
           "JerseyNumber":"84",
           "Position":"WR"
        },
        "team":{  
           "ID":"62",
           "City":"Green Bay",
           "Name":"Packers",
           "Abbreviation":"GB"
        },
        "stats":{  
           "GamesPlayed":{  
              "@abbreviation":"G",
              "#text":"8"
           },
           "RushAttempts":{  
              "@category":"Rushing",
              "@abbreviation":"Att",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "RushYards":{  
              "@category":"Rushing",
              "@abbreviation":"Yds",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "RushAverage":{  
              "@category":"Rushing",
              "@abbreviation":"Avg",
              "#text":"0.0"
           },
           "RushTD":{  
              "@category":"Rushing",
              "@abbreviation":"TD",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "RushLng":{  
              "@category":"Rushing",
              "@abbreviation":"Lng",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Rush20Plus":{  
              "@category":"Rushing",
              "@abbreviation":"20+",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Rush40Plus":{  
              "@category":"Rushing",
              "@abbreviation":"40+",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "RushFumbles":{  
              "@category":"Rushing",
              "@abbreviation":"Fum",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Targets":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"Tgt",
              "#text":"16"
           },
           "Receptions":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"Rec",
              "#text":"9"
           },
           "RecYards":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"Yds",
              "#text":"111"
           },
           "RecAverage":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"Avg",
              "#text":"12.3"
           },
           "RecTD":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"TD",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "RecLng":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"Lng",
              "#text":"32"
           },
           "Rec20Plus":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"20+",
              "#text":"1"
           },
           "Rec40Plus":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"40+",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "RecFumbles":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"Fumbles",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "TackleSolo":{  
              "@category":"Tackles",
              "@abbreviation":"Solo",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "TackleTotal":{  
              "@category":"Tackles",
              "@abbreviation":"Total",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "TackleAst":{  
              "@category":"Tackles",
              "@abbreviation":"Ast",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Sacks":{  
              "@category":"Tackles",
              "@abbreviation":"Sacks",
              "#text":"0.0"
           },
           "SackYds":{  
              "@category":"Tackles",
              "@abbreviation":"SackYds",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Safeties":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"Sfty",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Interceptions":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"Int",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "IntTD":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"TD",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "IntYds":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"Yds",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "IntAverage":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"Avg",
              "#text":"0.0"
           },
           "IntLng":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"Lng",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "PassesDefended":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"PD",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Stuffs":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"Stuffs",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "StuffYds":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"StuffYds",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "KB":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"KB",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Fumbles":{  
              "@category":"Fumbles",
              "@abbreviation":"Fum",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "FumLost":{  
              "@category":"Fumbles",
              "@abbreviation":"Lost",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "FumForced":{  
              "@category":"Fumbles",
              "@abbreviation":"Forced",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "FumOwnRec":{  
              "@category":"Fumbles",
              "@abbreviation":"OwnRec",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "FumOppRec":{  
              "@category":"Fumbles",
              "@abbreviation":"OppRec",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "FumRecYds":{  
              "@category":"Fumbles",
              "@abbreviation":"RecYds",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "FumTotalRec":{  
              "@category":"Fumbles",
              "@abbreviation":"TotalRec",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "FumTD":{  
              "@category":"Fumbles",
              "@abbreviation":"TD",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "KrRet":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Ret",
              "#text":"2"
           },
           "KrYds":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Yds",
              "#text":"52"
           },
           "KrAvg":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Avg",
              "#text":"26.0"
           },
           "KrLng":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Lng",
              "#text":"30"
           },
           "KrTD":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"TD",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Kr20Plus":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"20+",
              "#text":"2"
           },
           "Kr40Plus":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"40+",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "KrFC":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"FC",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "KrFum":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Fum",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "PrRet":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Ret",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "PrYds":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Yds",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "PrAvg":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Avg",
              "#text":"0.0"
           },
           "PrLng":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Lng",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "PrTD":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"TD",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Pr20Plus":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"20+",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Pr40Plus":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"40+",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "PrFC":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"FC",
              "#text":"1"
           },
           "PrFum":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Fum",
              "#text":"0"
           }
        }
     },
     {  
        "player":{  
           "ID":"6826",
           "LastName":"Abdullah",
           "FirstName":"Ameer",
           "JerseyNumber":"21",
           "Position":"RB"
        },
        "team":{  
           "ID":"61",
           "City":"Detroit",
           "Name":"Lions",
           "Abbreviation":"DET"
        },
        "stats":{  
           "GamesPlayed":{  
              "@abbreviation":"G",
              "#text":"16"
           },
           "RushAttempts":{  
              "@category":"Rushing",
              "@abbreviation":"Att",
              "#text":"143"
           },
           "RushYards":{  
              "@category":"Rushing",
              "@abbreviation":"Yds",
              "#text":"607"
           },
           "RushAverage":{  
              "@category":"Rushing",
              "@abbreviation":"Avg",
              "#text":"4.2"
           },
           "RushTD":{  
              "@category":"Rushing",
              "@abbreviation":"TD",
              "#text":"2"
           },
           "RushLng":{  
              "@category":"Rushing",
              "@abbreviation":"Lng",
              "#text":"36"
           },
           "Rush20Plus":{  
              "@category":"Rushing",
              "@abbreviation":"20+",
              "#text":"4"
           },
           "Rush40Plus":{  
              "@category":"Rushing",
              "@abbreviation":"40+",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "RushFumbles":{  
              "@category":"Rushing",
              "@abbreviation":"Fum",
              "#text":"4"
           },
           "Targets":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"Tgt",
              "#text":"38"
           },
           "Receptions":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"Rec",
              "#text":"25"
           },
           "RecYards":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"Yds",
              "#text":"183"
           },
           "RecAverage":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"Avg",
              "#text":"7.3"
           },
           "RecTD":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"TD",
              "#text":"1"
           },
           "RecLng":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"Lng",
              "#text":"36"
           },
           "Rec20Plus":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"20+",
              "#text":"1"
           },
           "Rec40Plus":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"40+",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "RecFumbles":{  
              "@category":"Receiving",
              "@abbreviation":"Fumbles",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "TackleSolo":{  
              "@category":"Tackles",
              "@abbreviation":"Solo",
              "#text":"4"
           },
           "TackleTotal":{  
              "@category":"Tackles",
              "@abbreviation":"Total",
              "#text":"4"
           },
           "TackleAst":{  
              "@category":"Tackles",
              "@abbreviation":"Ast",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Sacks":{  
              "@category":"Tackles",
              "@abbreviation":"Sacks",
              "#text":"0.0"
           },
           "SackYds":{  
              "@category":"Tackles",
              "@abbreviation":"SackYds",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Safeties":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"Sfty",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Interceptions":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"Int",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "IntTD":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"TD",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "IntYds":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"Yds",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "IntAverage":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"Avg",
              "#text":"0.0"
           },
           "IntLng":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"Lng",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "PassesDefended":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"PD",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Stuffs":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"Stuffs",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "StuffYds":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"StuffYds",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "KB":{  
              "@category":"Interceptions",
              "@abbreviation":"KB",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Fumbles":{  
              "@category":"Fumbles",
              "@abbreviation":"Fum",
              "#text":"5"
           },
           "FumLost":{  
              "@category":"Fumbles",
              "@abbreviation":"Lost",
              "#text":"2"
           },
           "FumForced":{  
              "@category":"Fumbles",
              "@abbreviation":"Forced",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "FumOwnRec":{  
              "@category":"Fumbles",
              "@abbreviation":"OwnRec",
              "#text":"2"
           },
           "FumOppRec":{  
              "@category":"Fumbles",
              "@abbreviation":"OppRec",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "FumRecYds":{  
              "@category":"Fumbles",
              "@abbreviation":"RecYds",
              "#text":"5"
           },
           "FumTotalRec":{  
              "@category":"Fumbles",
              "@abbreviation":"TotalRec",
              "#text":"2"
           },
           "FumTD":{  
              "@category":"Fumbles",
              "@abbreviation":"TD",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "KrRet":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Ret",
              "#text":"36"
           },
           "KrYds":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Yds",
              "#text":"1050"
           },
           "KrAvg":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Avg",
              "#text":"29.2"
           },
           "KrLng":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Lng",
              "#text":"104"
           },
           "KrTD":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"TD",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Kr20Plus":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"20+",
              "#text":"32"
           },
           "Kr40Plus":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"40+",
              "#text":"4"
           },
           "KrFC":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"FC",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "KrFum":{  
              "@category":"Kickoff Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Fum",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "PrRet":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Ret",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "PrYds":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Yds",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "PrAvg":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Avg",
              "#text":"0.0"
           },
           "PrLng":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Lng",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "PrTD":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"TD",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Pr20Plus":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"20+",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "Pr40Plus":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"40+",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "PrFC":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"FC",
              "#text":"0"
           },
           "PrFum":{  
              "@category":"Punt Returns",
              "@abbreviation":"Fum",
              "#text":"0"
           }
        }
     }
  ]}}
```